# Past tense of "he bears the weight"

Tags: verbs, past-participles

I'm trying to figure out what the correct past tense form of "he bears the weight" would be.

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bear#Verb_2) says that "bear" has a simple past "bore" and a past participle "borne", but I don't understand when one is used instead of the other.

So, would the correct form be

> He has bore the weight

or

> He has borne the weight

?

It would also be helpful if I could see example sentences for "borne" and "bore" to illuminate the distinction.

Comment: He bore the weight. He has borne the weight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Bore* is the past tense, *borne* is the past participle. The past participle is used in the present perfect construction *He has borne*.

Comment: Cheers, thank you.  I'm a native English speaker who grew up in the US.